# Looking for a good open-source IAM system

Tags: oauth-2.0, apache-syncope

I am a PhD student and my dissertation is in the IAM domain. I am looking for an open-source enterprise IAM system with support for federation of social identities. I will need to make some changes in both back-end policy evaluation side and federation side for my dissertation. Any recommendation on open source IAM products that I can use for my dissertation? My priorities are (1) availability of documentation, (2) product is extensible (3) code changes are easy to make, and (4) richness in features. Any advise would be highly appreciated. Also, I came across Apache Syncope and midPoint, and wondering which one would serve my purpose better. Thanks in advance for your input.

Regards,
MN

Answer (score 2):

Identity and Access Management deals with a broad range of challenges.

The two products you mentioned pay more attention to the "policy evaluation" side of IAM systems. However, I don't have much hands on experience on Apache Syncope to give comparison on them.

The "federation of social identities" side of the problem is more often handled by "identity providers". Gluu and Keycloak are two bigger open source IAM products that pay more attention to, but not limited to, that aspect.

Apart from federation of social identities, I think it is also quite interesting to take a look at identity federations, e.g. eduGAIN, which federate identities across corporate borders.